# SFTP - "EOF while reading packet" error in PhpStorm, works fine in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, phpstorm, webstorm, sftp, eof

I'm trying to get an SFTP connection working in PhpStorm. It works fine in FileZilla.

In the SSH config section of the STFP config, I enter host, username and auth type (password) and click Test Connection. It connects fine.

If I click OK and go dialog level back and click Test Connection on the main SFTP config, I get `Connection to dev.the-server.net failed. EOF while reading packet` error. Like wise when I close the SFTP config dialog, there is an EOF while reading packet error where a directory listing should be.

If I use the same credentials and connect by FTP**S**, I can get a remote directory listing and download files, but I get the end of file error trying to upload.

This all seems to be PhpStorm issue because I can upload and download fine with FileZilla. For workflow reasons, I really need PhpStorm to connect.

Any thoughts on where to start?

Images of the SFTP dialog:

**Main SFTP config**
[image: Main SFTP config]

**SSH section of SFTP config**
[image: SSH section of SFTP config]

Comment: *"Any thoughts on where to start?*" Contact JetBrains Support and submit support ticket. Can be done right from the IDE (from `Help` menu) or via [Submit a request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) link on [PhpStorm Forums page](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm). You may need to provide some logs .. which you can do there privately.

Comment: In the meantime, please check comments in the following tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-55638 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38929

Comment: @LazyOne I feel like product support is [often] infinitely slower than community support, particularly if a fellow user knows exactly what it is and can solve the issue in 30 seconds. I will open a ticket though. I added some pictures too.

Answer (score 7):

Restarting PhpStorm helped to solve the problem.

Comment: After changing the password of the user I indeed had to restart my PhpStorm

Comment: using Clion also face the same problem. fix it by two step : 1. change the sever password; 2. restart the Clion

Answer (score 1):

For me, it failed because `sftp-server` was configured with the wrong path in `sshd_config`, and [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/sftp-error-using-cyberduck-eof-while-reading-packet) saved me. so:

1. Find the correct path of `sftp-server` (the `whereis sftp-server` command may be help), e.g. `/usr/libexec/sftp-server`.
2. Set the correct path in `sshd_config` (most likely in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), e.g. `Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/sftp-server`.
3. Restart the `sshd` server (possibly `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` or `/usr/sbin/sshd restart`).
4. Restart your IDE.

Comment: This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've changed SSH settings, restarted SSH service, restarted PHPStorm but it didn't help. But when I restarted the whole server and then tried again it started to working again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't install openssh in server. You can try this command.

```bash
sudo apt-get install openssh-server

sudo systemctl enable ssh

sudo systemctl start ssh
```